# Query Collections containing an ObjectId within an Array in Mongo with Java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

in pure Javascript, I can write a query like this:

```
db.getCollection('someTable').find({
   someArray:{$elemMatch:{$eq:ObjectId("SomeObjectId")}}
});
```

Now I need to write this in Java.
Something like this.collection.find().filter...

But I don't seem to get it right. How's the statement above translated to java?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this you need to use mongo-client for java program.

Here is some snippet from mongo java

```
import com.mongodb.ErrorCategory;
import com.mongodb.MongoWriteException;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.conversions.Bson;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
public class DocumentDAO {


final MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(mongoURIString));
        final MongoDatabase mongoDatabase= mongoClient.getDatabase("Db");
        public DocumentDAO(final MongoDatabase mongoDatabase) {
                someCollection= mongoDatabase.getCollection("SomeCollecton");
            }

        Bson filter =new Document("objectId",objectName);

                 List <Document> all= someCollection.find(filter).into( new ArrayList<Document>());
                  for(Document cur:all)
                  {
                    obj=cur;
                  }}
```

Maven could be used to download latest mongo driver for java

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-rc0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you looking for:

```
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
    MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase("test");
    db.getCollection("someTable").find(new BasicDBObject("someArray", new BasicDBObject("$elemMatch", new BasicDBObject("$eq", new BsonObjectId(new ObjectId("SomeObjectId"))))));
```